# Where is it possible to legally obtain powdered alcohol in the USA and Canada?

Tags: canada, palcohol

I recently came across this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_powder) on alcohol powder or powdered alcohol, which is also known as *palcohol*.

!n 2014, [Popular Science](http://www.popsci.com/article/technology/how-make-powdered-booze-home) had this to say about palachol:

> Palcohol will be available in vodka and rum varieties, as well as mojito, margarita, and other premixed cocktail flavors. It was officially approved by the Alcohol and Tobacco Tax and Trade Bureau (TTB) earlier this month, and Mark Phillips, its creator, says we can expect to see it in stores this fall.

[image: Palcohol]

[Palcohol Label](http://www.palcohol.com/)

Some States have already banned this product, so I would like to know where I could obtain legally powdered alcohol in the USA or Canada, if at all?

All you need is water to mix with the powder and you have a normal alcohol drink.

Comment: I'd dispute the "all you need is water... and you have a normal alcoholic drink". That was the marketing hype, but considering it's 55% ethanol and ~45% cyclodextrin, and all the flavors are necessarily going to be essences, I wouldn't call the end result "normal" in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Steve S. says, the "Palcohol" product does not seem to be on the market at the moment, and [their FAQ](http://www.palcohol.com/f.a.q..html) states *"When will it be available? As soon as we can. We're working on it. No samples will be released ahead of time."*... but in the meantime, you could always buy some cyclodextrin powder (easily sourceable from Amazon US), put your favorite [azeotropic firewater](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/6561/what-is-the-strongest-drink-in-the-world) into a spray bottle and spray it on, if you were so inclined. [Here](https://www.google.com/patents/US3795747) is a 1974 patent describing a process that gets to ~60% ethanol by weight of end product; in the same ballpark as the "Palcohol" packet mentions.

Thunderf00t has suggested [using feminine pads](https://youtu.be/0c0QLaVLhTs?t=493) instead as a better all-round idea.

Answer (score 3):

In the same Wikipedia article you mention, it also says:

> However, as of January 4, 2016, the product is not yet available for sale and legalization remains controversial due to public-health and other concerns. Researchers have expressed concern that, should the product go into production, increases in alcohol misuse, abuse, and associated physical harm to its consumers could occur above what has been historically associated with liquid alcohol alone.

I went to the website and it looks like he's looking for investors to start production. You need to buy the rights to produce it in a certain country. My gut is telling me there is no mass market for this product and things have stalled out.